# knockout Mapping for array of objects, for certain properties using 'observe'

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I would like to make a deep copy of the below array. And the `result` should observe only the `count` property.

```
 data = [{
        id: 1,
        code: 'ABC',
        count: ko.observable(0)
    },{
        id: 2,
        code: 'JKL',
        count: ko.observable(5)
    },{
        id: 3,
        code: 'QWE',
        count: ko.observable(1)
    }]
```

I tried `ko.mapping.fromJS(ko.mapping.toJS(data));` but `id` and  `code` was also converted to observables.
Currently I am using the below code to get the expected result.

```
 var obj = ko.mapping.toJS(data);
 var result = [];
 obj.forEach(function(o){
     var obs = ko.mapping.fromJS(o, {
         'observe': "count"
     });
     result.push(obs);
 });
// result will give the expected result
```

Here I have used `forEach` to loop each object in the `data` array. Is there a way to avoid the forEach loop ? or How to observe only the count property in array of object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the `forEach` as well as observe only `count` like this:

```
var result = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {observe: 'count'});
console.log(result());
```

---

**Edit**:

According to the docs, we don't even need to mention `ko.observable` in our data. It should simply pick that up based on our 'observe' parameter. So maybe you might want to modify your `data` like this:

```
var data = [{
                id: 1,
                code: 'ABC',
                count: 0
            }, {
                id: 2,
                code: 'JKL',
                count: 5
            }, {
                id: 3,
                code: 'QWE',
                count: 1
            }];
```

And then, using `forEach`,

```
var result = [];
data.forEach(function(o){
    result.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(o, {observe:'count'}));
});
console.log(result);
```

It's up to you, which method you would prefer to use.

Comment: Thanks Ray.
So if my data doesn't have observables (as mentioned in the answer) only the second method work ?